# Estou tentando fazer um upgrade do spring security 3.0.5 para o 4.2.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring, spring-security

Estou tentando mudar do spring security 3.0.5 para o 4.2.3 porem estou tendo um problema seríssimo de dependências. Nesse projeto fui obrigado a não utilizar o mavem ou algo do tipo. E o problema (Acabei de adicionar a biblioteca que funciona parcialmente) é entre as duas bibliotecas do spring-web a 3.0.5 e a 4.2.5. A 4.2.5 possui uma classe RequestEntity que eu utilizo para geração de um tokem para requisição em um web service porem a 3.0.5 que o spring-security está configurado não possui essa classe que a versão mais nova tem. E quando executo o formulário ele executa o a biblioteca mais antiga e como ela não tem essa classe não consigo gerar o token. E não sei como passo o spring security para o 4.2.5.
– 
  Meu root-context:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd"
```

Meu security.xml

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd"
```

Meu servelt-context.xml

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd"
```

Minha Biblioteca
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Biblioteca que funciona porem com o problema no web-service
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De onde essa dependência `org.springframework.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar` está vindo? Está usando maven, gradle ou algo do tipo, consegue enviar a hierarquia de dependências? Qual é esse problema "seríssimo de dependência"?

Comment: Nesse projeto fui obrigado a não utilizar o mavem ou algo do tipo. E o problema (Acabei de adicionar a biblioteca que funciona parcialmente) é entre as duas bibliotecas do spring-web a 3.0.5 e a 4.2.5. A 4.2.5 possui uma classe RequestEntity que eu utilizo para geração de um tokem para requisição em um web service porem a 3.0.5 que o spring-security está configurado não possui essa classe que a versão mais nova tem. E quando executo o formulário ele executa o a biblioteca mais antiga e como ela não tem essa classe não consigo gerar o token. E não sei como passo o spring security para o 4.2.5.

Comment: Como passo para o 4.2.5 fazendo o menor numero de alterações possíveis.